# How can I use more than one function to filter an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, filter, es6-promise

I want to use filter1 and filter2 functions in generalFilter but I can't comprehend the right syntax to do it in Javascript.

```
const filter1 = (
  array
) => {

  return array.filter((parameter, index) => {
    return (
      !parameter.isOptional()
    );
  });
};

const filter2 = (
  array
) => {

  return array.filter((parameter, index) => {
    return (
      !parameter.isEmpty()
    );
  });
};

const filterGeneral = (
  array
) => {
  return array.filter(filter1(array) && filter2(array));
};
```

This is apprx. what I am trying to do but I am not able to manage to succeed, and I didn't like my logic. Is there any way to do this properly?

Comment: `array.filter(func1).filter(func2)`

Answer (score 4):

You could use a *pipe* function, where you take some function and take the result from the first function as input for the second function, and so on.

```
const
    pipe = (...functions) => input => functions.reduce((acc, fn) => fn(acc), input),
    filter1 = array => array.filter((parameter, index) => !parameter.isOptional()),
    filter2 = array => array.filter((parameter, index) => !parameter.isEmpty()),
    filterGeneral = pipe(filter1, filter2),
    array = [{ ... }, { ... }],
    result = filterGeneral(array);
```

Comment: Very intersting approach, why (if it is) is this better than just chaining multiple filter functions?

Comment: it works with any type, because it is independent of array's prototype functions.

Answer (score 2):

Has they are two different filters, you can only apply one at a time over the parameter itself, so I think you should apply one to another:

```
const filterGeneral = array => filter1(filter2(array));
```

Comment: I would probably filter first by `filter1` _then_ `filter2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just chain multitple `filter()` methods like this:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

array.filter((elem) => elem > 2).filter((elem) => elem > 3);
// returns [4, 5]
```

This works because [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns the filtered array. You can just filter this array again.

This means that the example above is the same as writing this:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const tmp = array.filter((elem) => elem > 2);
tmp.filter((elem) => elem > 3);
```

Comment: The functions do the acual filtering, so it doesn't make sense to pass them into `.filter` as a callback.

Comment: @Andy I just realised right after hitting answer and edited my answer